# Exporting symbols in static library that is linked to dynamic library

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, dynamic-linking, dllexport

I have the following scenario in MSVC2017:

1. A static library with the function `bool foo()`
2. A dynamic link library that links to the static library above
3. An application that loads the dynamic link library using explicit run-time linking and calls `foo()` via `GetProcAddress`

In the static library, `foo()` is defined as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool foo() 
{
    return true;   
}
```

Now, because `foo()` is not used by the dynamic link library, its symbol is not exported and thus not findable when the application used `GetProcAddress`.

I have tried:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/include:foo")`

and:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/export:foo")`

I can see the exported `foo()` using Dependency Walker if I move the definition to the dynamic link library (not a viable solution) but I cannot seem to get the symbol exported when I keep the definition in the static library with the above linker switches. I presume this is because the symbol is still not used, and thus still not exported regardless?

I would like a solution for both MSVC on Windows and Clang on Linux. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried both the `/include:foo` (to force including that symbol in the DLL) and `/export:foo` (to export that symbol) options at the same time?  You might need to use the mangled name (`_foo@0` or something like that).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I tried it just now but to no avail. I didn't decorate the name as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2017):
"Note that in a 64-bit environment, functions are not decorated"

Comment: Does your static lib have a *.h* file?

Answer (score 4):

You're doing something wrong (or at least not as you describe in the question). Of course, what you posted in your answer works as well, but that's only a workaround, as the "regular" way should work.
Here's a small example.

*lib00.cpp*:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool foo()
{
    return true;
}
```

*dll00.cpp*:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool bar()
{
    return false;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056330888]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> lib00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /D_LIB /DSTATIC /Folib00.obj lib00.cpp
> lib00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> lib /nologo /out:lib00.lib lib00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /DDLL /Fodll00.obj dll00.cpp
> dll00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00.dll dll00.obj lib00.lib
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> lib00.cpp
> lib00.lib
> lib00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            1 number of functions
>            1 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: ----- Re-link dll, instructing it to include foo -----
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /include:foo /out:dll00.dll dll00.obj lib00.lib
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            2 number of functions
>            2 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>           2    1 00001010 foo
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
> ```

**Notes**:

- As noticed, I used command line, but the same commands (more arguments) are invoked by *VStudio* *IDE*
- Adding ***/include:foo*** (2<sup>nd</sup> *Link* command) exports *foo* as well (as seen in the next *DumpBin* output):

  - Specifying this option is identical to adding `#pragma comment(linker, "/include:foo")` (in ***dll.cpp*** - or any file that is being directly passed to the linker)
  - */export:foo* is not necessary, as the function is already exported by *__declspec(dllexport)*
- I didn't go through the end (the application), since *foo* being present in *DumpBin* output is enough (it's also visible from *Dependency Walker*)

---

#### Update *#0*

You might not be doing things wrong after all. But bear in mind that **it's not scalable** (if you have hundreds of such symbols). Looking at [[MS.Learn]: Overview of LIB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/overview-of-lib), it provides the same options as *Link* in regards to exporting stuff. But they seem to be ignored.

When building a *.lib*, maybe one would like to specify all the symbols to be included at link time (either via option or via *#pragma comment*), when **building the *.lib***, and not when linking. Apparently, they are ignored (I've tested it), unless stuff is specified in *.obj* files (or options) passed directly to the linker. This is because [[MS.Learn]: Building an Import Library and Export File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/building-an-import-library-and-export-file) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Note that if you create your import library in a preliminary step, before creating your .dll, **you must pass the same set of object files when building the .dll, as you passed when building the import library**.

So there's a difference when passing an *.obj* file to the linker:

- Directly (command line): it is included in the *.dll* (or *.exe*)
- Indirectly (part of a *.lib* passed via command line): it is not included in the *.dll*, it is only searched for symbols

This totally makes sense as a lib is just a collection (archive) of *.obj* files (on *Nix* the archiver is *Ar* (formerly known as *RanLib*)). An example:

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> del *.obj *.exp *.lib *.dll
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> lib00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /D_LIB /DSTATIC /Folib00.obj lib00.cpp
> lib00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /DDLL /Fodll00.obj dll00.cpp
> dll00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Pass lib00.obj directly to linker
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00.dll dll00.obj lib00.obj
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> lib /nologo /out:lib00.lib lib00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir
>  Volume in drive E is SSD0-WORK
>  Volume Serial Number is AE9E-72AC
>
>  Directory of e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056330888
>
> 23/01/30  09:15    <DIR>          .
> 23/01/30  09:15    <DIR>          ..
> 23/01/30  09:12                72 dll00.cpp
> 23/01/30  09:14           106,496 dll00.dll
> 23/01/30  09:14               733 dll00.exp
> 23/01/30  09:14             1,790 dll00.lib
> 23/01/30  09:14               604 dll00.obj
> 23/01/30  09:07                71 lib00.cpp
> 23/01/30  09:15               822 lib00.lib
> 23/01/30  09:13               604 lib00.obj
>                8 File(s)        111,192 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)  51,727,843,328 bytes free
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            2 number of functions
>            2 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>           2    1 00001010 foo
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Now do the same with the one from inside the .lib
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> del lib00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> lib lib00.lib /extract:lib00.obj
> Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.16.27048.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir lib00.obj
>  Volume in drive E is SSD0-WORK
>  Volume Serial Number is AE9E-72AC
>
>  Directory of e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056330888
>
> 23/01/30  09:16               604 lib00.obj
>                1 File(s)            604 bytes
>                0 Dir(s)  51,727,839,232 bytes free
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00.dll dll00.obj lib00.obj
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            2 number of functions
>            2 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>           2    1 00001010 foo
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
> ```

---

#### Update *#1*

I played briefly with [[MS.Learn]: Linker options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options) (***/INCLUDE*** and ***/EXPORT***). Added a bit of complexity into the mix.

*lib01.cpp*:

```cpp
//#pragma comment(linker, "/include:foo1")  // Apparently, has no effect in an .obj contained by a .lib
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:foo01")

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif


__declspec(dllexport) bool foo00()
{
    return true;
}

bool foo01()
{
    return true;
}

bool foo02()
{
    return true;
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*lib10.cpp*:

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:foo11")

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif


__declspec(dllexport) bool foo10()
{
    return true;
}

bool foo11()
{
    return true;
}

bool foo12()
{
    return true;
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [prompt]> del *.obj *.exp *.lib *.dll
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /D_LIB /DSTATIC /Folib01.obj lib01.cpp
> lib01.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /D_LIB /DSTATIC /Folib10.obj lib10.cpp
> lib10.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> lib /nologo /out:lib0110.lib lib01.obj lib10.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /DDLL /Fodll00.obj dll00.cpp
> dll00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: ----- "Regular" behavior -----
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00.dll dll00.obj lib0110.lib
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            1 number of functions
>            1 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: ----- /export a symbol -----
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00_export.dll /export:foo02 dll00.obj lib0110.lib
>    Creating library dll00_export.lib and object dll00_export.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00_export.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00_export.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00_export.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            2 number of functions
>            2 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>           2    1 0000E1A0 foo02
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: ----- /include a symbol -----
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00_include.dll /include:foo02 dll00.obj lib0110.lib
>    Creating library dll00_include.lib and object dll00_include.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00_include.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00_include.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00_include.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            3 number of functions
>            3 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>           2    1 00001010 foo00
>           3    2 00001020 foo01
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
> ```

As seen (just like in the *Doc*s):

- ***/EXPORT***: searches (in the *.lib*) for the symbol (*foo02*) and simply exports it
- ***/INCLUDE***: searches (in the *.lib*) for the symbol (*foo02*), gets the containing object file (*lib0.obj*), and **includes it in the *.dll***:

  - As a consequence, the other 2 symbols (*foo00*, *foo01*) marked for export in the *.obj* file are exported

#### Conclusion

Took a deeper look and found **[[MS.Learn]: /WHOLEARCHIVE (Include All Library Object Files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/wholearchive-include-all-library-object-files)** which states (**emphasis** is mine):

> The /WHOLEARCHIVE option forces the linker to **include every object file** from either a specified static library, or if no library is specified, **from all static libraries** specified to the LINK command. 
> ... 
> **The /WHOLEARCHIVE option was introduced in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.**

**Output**:

> ```
> [prompt]> :: ----- YAY ----- /wholearchive ----- YAY -----
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> link /nologo /dll /out:dll00_wholearchive.dll /wholearchive:lib0110.lib dll00.obj lib0110.lib
>    Creating library dll00_wholearchive.lib and object dll00_wholearchive.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports dll00_wholearchive.dll
>
> Dump of file dll00_wholearchive.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00_wholearchive.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            5 number of functions
>            5 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 bar
>           2    1 00001040 foo00
>           3    2 00001050 foo01
>           4    3 00001010 foo10
>           5    4 00001020 foo11
>
>   Summary
>
>         2000 .data
>         1000 .gehcont
>         1000 .gxfg
>         1000 .pdata
>         9000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         E000 .text
> ```

Comment: Is here any way to finished using only source code? /Include suits my needs. But if there are lots symbols to export, maintaining the list of  /INCLUDE become complicated. And, /wholearchive is absolutely not usable because it export everything.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in the end was to make a dummy function that called `foo()` to force all symbols in that compilation unit to be exported.