# __declspec(dllexport) static linked libraries to dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static-linking, dllexport

I have a simple project setup for an OpenGL-project for University.

An API project where every library I want to use (GLEW, GLFW, GLM) is linked statically. These libraries should be combined with my own API code into one single DLL file.

The other project should only have one dependency, the DLL. Throw that DLL it should get access to the API code and all libraries linked inside the API.

My problem is that inside the API I have access to all functions of all libraries I linked. But inside the actual project which has the API as a dependency, I can call the functions and the compiler throws out no error (of cause) because the function declaration is in the linked header files but the linker does not find the function definition inside the DLL, which mean the build of the API does not export the linked libraries into the DLL.

In the API project, I also defined the necessary preprocessor definitions:

I defined `_GLFW_BUILD_DLL:`

```
from "glfw3.h" l. 233-245

/* GLFWAPI is used to declare public API functions for export
 * from the DLL / shared library / dynamic library.
 */
#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(_GLFW_BUILD_DLL)
    /* We are building GLFW as a Win32 DLL */
    #define GLFWAPI __declspec(dllexport)         <----- this one is active
#elif defined(_WIN32) && defined(GLFW_DLL)
    /* We are calling GLFW as a Win32 DLL */
    #define GLFWAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(_GLFW_BUILD_DLL)
    /* We are building GLFW as a shared / dynamic library */
    #define GLFWAPI __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
    /* We are building or calling GLFW as a static library */
    #define GLFWAPI
#endif
```

I defined `GLEW_BUILD:`

```
from "glew.h" l. 200-208

#ifdef GLEW_STATIC
    #define GLEWAPI extern
#else
    #ifdef GLEW_BUILD
        #define GLEWAPI extern __declspec(dllexport) <---- this one is active
    #else
        #define GLEWAPI extern __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif
```

Any help?

**EDIT:**

The linker options:

```
/OUT:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\CGAPI\bin\Debug\Win32\CGAPI.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\CGAPI\bin\Debug\Win32\CGAPI.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "glew32s.lib" "glfw3.lib" "opengl32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\CGAPI\bin\Debug\Win32\CGAPI.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\CGAPI\bin\Debug\Win32\CGAPI.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:NO /ManifestFile:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\CGAPI\bin-int\Debug\Win32\CGAPI.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\Dependencies\GLFW\Win32\lib-vc2019\" /LIBPATH:"D:\Programmierung\C++-Projekte\CG-Project\Dependencies\GLEW\lib\Release\Win32\" /TLBID:1
```

The one I added:

```
/WHOLEARCHIVE:glew32s.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:glfw3.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:opengl32.lib
```

**EDIT 2:**

So I had to download the source code from glew and build it myself and also I had to remove the `.res` file inside the option of my own glew build. Now the API builds successfully but the methods aren't part of the DLL. So nothing changed.

Comment: When you build the DLL, you will also (or should) generate an *import library* - this will look like a static library, in some respects (on Windows, it will have the `.lib` extension). You must make sure that this library is  included by the linker when building the application that calls the DLL, as this tells the linker that the relevant functions are loaded (at run time) from the DLL.

Comment: I already did that. So I can use my self-written API code. And there the linker of cause does not throw any LNK2019 error. But when I want to call for example `glfwMakeContextCurrent` or `glewInit` which are functions from the static linked libs, the linker does not find them which means they are not part of the DLL or the smaller LIB included by the linker.

Comment: Ah, OK - got it. I'll need to think some more ... bedtime here now, so I'll get back in a few hours. (Or somebody else may help out.)

Comment: You'll probably have to list the functions as `EXPORTS` in a [Module Definition File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=vs-2019) when building the DLL. Not sure if that will be sufficient to let the EXE know that they're in that DLL, though.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.You want to access your and *GL* *API* as well? then why not use the *.dlls*? Also how did you get the static *.lib*s? If that macro is define when you build your *.dll*, it doesn't mean it was active when building the *.lib*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330888/exporting-symbols-in-static-library-that-is-linked-to-dynamic-library.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What if the user of your DLL also uses OpenGL DLLs? The normal approach is to simply redistribute the GL DLLs together with your DLL.

Comment: It is a totally nonsense that you are trying to do. Why would you like to embed some libraries and export the the same functions, since these functions are already exported and you can provide libraries separately? You provide no advantage in doing this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your motivation for doing things this way. The common approach (that I'd also use) is shipping the *OpenGL* *.dll*s (I'm not aware of the licensing implications) along with yours.

However, even if **this looks like an *XY Problem***, in order to achieve your goal, you could pass [[MS.Docs]: /WHOLEARCHIVE (Include All Library Object Files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/wholearchive-include-all-library-object-files) to the linker. In order to differentiate which *.lib*s to include and which not, specify the flag once per each target library: `/wholearchive:glew32.lib /wholearchive:glfw3.lib /wholearchive:glm.lib`.

Check [[SO]: Exporting symbols in static library that is linked to dynamic library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56826559/4788546) for more details.

As a note: the *.lib*s must have been built with exportable symbols. If not, you'll have to export them "manually", using one of the other choices:

- */EXPORT* linker option
- Module definition (*.def*) files

or rebuild the *.lib* as static but with exportable symbols. However, there's high chance it won't work *OOTB* (you'll probably need to modify a file or 2 or manually pass a compile flag), as it's not a normal way (most of the people would agree that's a *NO-NO*, especially for someone without a fairly deep know-how) of doing things.

Comment: SO I added the /WHOLEARCHIVE option. Now I get to LNK2005 error that `user32.lib` and `gdi32.lib` want to redefine `__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` which was already defined in `kernel.lib`

Comment: Now I get the error that `glew32s.lib` was already specified because I added the LIBs as additional dependencies. So in the linker options, there is an option called `/DYNAMICBASE` which already specifies `glew32s.lib`. And then I try to respecify it with the flag `/WHOLEARCHIVE`

Comment: /dynamicbase does not require any name. Perhaps you should place the linker command in the question.

Comment: Ok, one the 3 added libs doesn't seem to match the one specified at the beginning. Also the linker output (error) is missing. There is some other stuff missing, so to be frank, I'm not sure how this should go on, cause I don;t feel like asking for every little piece of info and debugging via comments.

Comment: Can I upload the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211240/discussion-between-cristifati-and-matze).

Comment: So I had to download the source code from glew and build it myself and also I had to remove the `.res` file inside the option of my own glew build. Now the API builds successfully but the methods aren't part of the DLL. So nothing changed.