# How do I create a static library (.lib) which depends on the dynamic (.dll) tensorflow library?

Tags: c, tensorflow, dll, visual-studio-2019, static-libraries

I have created a static C library in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 which depends on the tensorflow library, which is dynamic (.dll). My library, lets call it A.lib, contains a function which takes data, pass it to a tensorflow model and returns the model's output. The compilation seems to work well and creates an A.lib file.

Now I want to use my static library in another project to create an .exe. Lets call it B. I copied the header A.h and the A.lib into the B project and adapt the project properties so that my library can be found.

The problem is that I get LNK2001 errors, because the linker can not find the definitions of the tensorflow functions which I call in my A.lib.

I tried to copy the tensorflow lib into my project B as well. But that did not help.

What do I have to do to include the libraries correctly? Or is there a simpler alternative to deploy a convolutional neural network in C?

Comment: Did you try adding *TensorFlow* *.lib* in the project settings (linker) when building the *.exe*? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330888/exporting-symbols-in-static-library-that-is-linked-to-dynamic-library/56826559#56826559, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091164/declspecdllexport-static-linked-libraries-to-dll/61103435#61103435 might help.

Comment: @CristiFati Yes I added the _TensorFlow .lib_ in the project settings. Thanks for the links, but they describe how to include .libs into a .dll. I want to do the opposite. But from your comment, I realize that my plan should be possible in principle. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

*dll00.h*:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(DLL00_EXPORTS)
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API int dll00Func00();

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*dll00.c*:

```c
#define DLL00_EXPORTS
#include "dll00.h"

#include <stdio.h>


int dll00Func00() {
    printf("%s - %d - %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    return -3;
}
```

*lib00.h*:

```c
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

int lib00Func00();

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*lib00.c*:

```c
#include "lib00.h"

#include "dll00.h"

#include <stdio.h>


int lib00Func00() {
    printf("%s - %d - %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    return dll00Func00() - 3;
}
```

*main00.c*:

```c
#include "lib00.h"

#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    printf("%s - %d - %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__);
    int res = lib00Func00();
    printf("Lib func returned: %d\n", res);
    printf("\nDone.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```batch
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q069197545]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 >nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.c
> dll00.h
> lib00.c
> lib00.h
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .dll (1 step)
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .lib (2 steps)
> [prompt]> cl /c /nologo /MD /Folib00.obj lib00.c
> lib00.c
>
> [prompt]> lib /NOLOGO /OUT:lib00.lib lib00.obj
>
> [prompt]> :: Build .exe (1 step)
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 main00.c  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main00_pc064.exe lib00.lib dll00.lib
> main00.c
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.h
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> lib00.c
> lib00.h
> lib00.lib
> lib00.obj
> main00.c
> main00.obj
> main00_pc064.exe
>
> [prompt]> main00_pc064.exe
> main00.c - 7 - main
> lib00.c - 9 - lib00Func00
> dll00.c - 8 - dll00Func00
> Lib func returned: -6
>
> Done.
> ```

So, it works (at least this trivial example). 
As seen, when building the *.exe* I also passed the *.dll*'s *.lib* to the linker (meaning that **the *.dll* (together with all its (recurring) dependents) is required at runtime**). For info on how to do it on the *VStudio* project, check [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156336/how-to-include-openssl-in-visual-studio/32158521#32158521).

Comment: @ChristiFati I was able to reproduce this minimal example. I am now trying to apply this to my specific project. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Codefactory: Glad to hear that. Let me know how it works out.