Errors with '__declspec' in C++ 20
Alright. Let me describe my issue. So, have this macro:
#ifdef DLL_MODE
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

And this class:
class DLL_API Test
{

public:

    void print();
};

And here's the implementation, which is in a static library.
#include "../LibTest/Test.hpp"

void Test::print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}

Seems simple enough right? Well, not so much... So, my main issue is that when compiling, I get a linker error:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl Test::print(void)" (__imp_?print@Test@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main

However if I were to remove the 'DLL_API' from my 'Test' class, then the error goes away. However, I need the 'DLL_API' there in the first place, as I have some dll loading things I need to do that require the 'DLL_API' macro. Also, 'DLL_MODE' is defined when building the static library.
I have tried switching the macros around, asking ChatGPT, googling it, but nothing really worked.

Where do you set DLL_MODE and to what values?

I set DLL_MODE in the C++ preprocessor

Why use DLL macros on the class Test in a static library?  Does this answer your question? dllimport /dllexport and static libraries compilation under visual c++

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551640/4788546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56826559/4788546.

In Visual Studio, __declspec(dllimport) is  optional for functions in DLL.
So you can use
#ifdef DLL_MODE
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API 
#endif

And only add DLL_MODE when building the DLL, static libraries do not need to export symbols.

Wait, I thought you needed '__declspec(dllimport)' in the main console application that links to the static library/dll, not in the static library/dll itself. Also, don't you actually need '__declspec(dllexport)' in the static library/dll to export the symbols to be passed along, while you need '__declspec(dllimport)' to import the symbols into the console application?

For some context, What I am trying to do is make a game engine in C++ that has DLL modding capabilities. The way you would make a game with my engine is by actually creating a dll mod, and then having it manage all of the gameplay by using the mesh class, and other things provided by the game engine. But, the issue I'm running into is that I could have a singleton class, both my game engine and mod dll use it, however the mod dll does not actually modify anything in the main game engine. The way I want to solve this is by exporting the symbols made by the dll to the game engine     --continued

--continued     so that the main game engine application can have its values modified. However, I am running into issues like the ones I posted this question about.

The question you raised in the comment is different from the original question. You should post a new question about your DLL and game engine. console screenshot

Have you tried building the example in the question into a  DLL and use it in console  without __declspec(dllimport)?

This answer is a good comment on the code, but not an answer to the question. I think you gave the answer indirectly as a comment to the question, the problem is caused by using DLL-methods in a static library, where they don't fit.

@Minxin Yu - MSFT
Yes, I have. But, now the aformentioned singleton class issues arise, as the mod dlls cannot modify things in the host process

@Ulrich Eckhardt
Then how do I communicate symbols between classes? I need to use '__declspec(dllimport)' to import symbols from dlls, however... Well, I am just not sure.

@SoulStealer173: This was more intended at Minxin Yu. That said, you now talk about DLLs, but in the question above you talk about a static lib, which makes this really confusing. In any case, don't use singletons, they are just globals in a nice package, but with all the problems that global mutable data causes. Use dependency injection instead. Also, for your use case, you neither need static libs nor regular DLLs, but rather a plugin mechanism that allows explicitly loading a DLL at runtime instead of during startup.
